# Inverse image and pushforward are adjoint

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm trying to understand why the inverse image functor is left adjoint to the pushforward sheaf functor

> Given $\pi:X \rightarrow Y$, show $Mor(\mathcal{\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G}}, \mathcal{F})$ is in natural bijection with $Mor(\mathcal{G},\pi_* \mathcal{F})$

I was pretty stuck with this until I started thinking about the special case where I want to consider $X = \{pt\}$ and $\mathcal{F}(pt) = S$ for some set $S$.

So I understand that then the inverse image sheaf at the poin $\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G}(pt)$ is just the stalk $\mathcal{G}_p$, where $p$ is the image of the point $\{pt\}$ in Y, and $\pi_*\mathcal{F}$ is the skyscraper sheaf with the set $S$ at $p$.

What I'm confused by is that if the two fucntors are adjoint, then the data of morhpisms of sheaves $Mor(\mathcal{\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G}}, \mathcal{F})$ is the same as the data of morphisms in $Mor(\mathcal{G},\pi_* \mathcal{F})$. So in our case, the data of maps $\mathcal{G}_p \rightarrow S$ should be the same as the morphisms of sheaves $\mathcal{G} \rightarrow \pi_* \mathcal{F}$. But I don't see why that should be the case. To my mind, the data of a map from $\mathcal{G}_p \rightarrow S$ only remembers the information of $\mathcal{G}$ *'at'* $p$ but doesn't the latter remember the information of $\mathcal{G}$ for any open neighborhood around $p$? i.e. we have a family of maps $\mathcal{G}(V) \rightarrow \pi_*\mathcal{F}(V)$ and not just the information at $p$.

To put it more formally, given $\phi \in Mor(\pi^{-1}\mathcal{G},\mathcal{F})$, how specifically do we construct a single morphism $\psi \in Mor(\mathcal{G},\pi_*\mathcal{F})$ in this specific case?

Going backwards seems fine as for any $\psi \in Mor(\mathcal{G}, \pi_*\mathcal{F})$, we may take the induced map of stalks

Side note: I did find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878201/stalk-functor-is-adjoint-to-the-skyscraper-functor) which basically asks the same question. The answer seems to suggest that it is clear why the two sets of morphisms contain the same data by the definition of a colimit or in more generality by Yoneda's lemma, but I don't see why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pi_*\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf which assigns to an open set $U$ the value $S$ if $pt\in U$ and the singleton set $\{*\}$ otherwise. A morphism $\mathcal{G}\to \pi_*\mathcal{F}$ is a compatible system of maps $\mathcal{G}(U)\to (\pi_*\mathcal{F})(U)$ for all open $U\subset Y$. In particular, as $U$ ranges over all opens containing $f(pt)$, we get a exactly what we need to determine a map $\mathcal{G}_{f(pt)}\to S$ by taking the direct limit; conversely, given a map $\mathcal{G}_{f(pt)}\to S$ we can construct a map $\mathcal{G}\to\pi_*\mathcal{F}$ by declaring the map on an open set $U\subset Y$ to be $\mathcal{G}(U)\to\mathcal{G}_{pt}\to S=\pi_*\mathcal{F}(U)$ whenever $f(pt)\in U$ and the unique map $\mathcal{G}(U)\to \{*\}=\pi_*\mathcal{F}(U)$ when $f(pt)\notin U$.